# Img overflowing a fixed-width div in IE and FF

Tags: html, css

I have a relatively small problem here, it doesnt appear in Chrome though.

I have 2 divs at 50% `width` of their container, one is floated to the left, the other floated to the right. One contains some text, and the other contains nothing but an image which has a `max-width: 100%` applied to it by default. But still, the image is overflowing to the left outside of the divs boundaries. How to fix?

http://jsfiddle.net/Pv5Cb/ - I am not sure if this will give you an idea about what is happening but still.

P.S. I am using some snippets from [animate.css](http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/), but I doubt that this is the problem.

HTML:

```
<div class="content-project-left">
    <h1>heading one</h1>
    <p>paragraph</p>
</div>

<div class="content-project-right">
    <div>
        <a>
            <img src="img/img.jpg" alt=""/>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it myself.

So it turned out that besides the two 50% sides that are floated to the left and right respectfully, I gave the image within the floated right div a float: right...

float: *; removes an element from its natural document flow.

Removed it and everything is back to normal now.

Comment: hey ben needs your help on the chat